# Appending an image to a webpage from a function

Tags: javascript, html, image, appendchild

I am creating a website where a function goes through an array of images and picks one at random.

I would like to be able to choose where the image is displayed specifically on the webpage, rather than just at the bottom which seems to be the default.

Here is my code for the function displayRandomHats():

```
<script> 
    
    
function displayRandomHats()   
{  
   //array of images with image location, height, and width  
  
 var imageArray = [  
   {   
     //address URL of the image  
     src: "Images/GreenGiantsHat.JPEG",  
     //size for the image to be display on webpage  
     width: "200",  
     height:"200"

       
   },   
   {  
     src: "Images/LMUHat.JPEG",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "Images/NYHat.JPEG",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"  
   },  
   {  
     src: "Images/OrangeGiantsHat.JPEG",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"
    },  
   {  
     src: "Images/WolfHat.JPEG",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"
    } ];  
      
    //find the length of the array of images  
    var arrayLength = imageArray.length;  
    var newArray = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {  
        newArray[i] = new Image(); 
        newArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src;  
        newArray[i].width = imageArray[i].width;  
        newArray[i].height = imageArray[i].height;  
    }  
     
  // create random image number  
  function getRandomNum(min, max)   
  {  
      // generate and return a random number for the image to be displayed   
      imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
      return newArray[imgNo];  
  }    
  
  // 0 is first image and (preBuffer.length - 1) is last image of the array  
  var newImage = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);  
   
  // remove the previous images  
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');  
  var l = images.length;  
  for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {  
     ;  
  }  
  
    // display the new random image

  document.body.appendChild(newImage);  
}  
    
</script>
```

This last part, the "document.body.appendChild(newImage)" is what I think will be part of dictating where the image goes. I feel like the image should go into a div that I have set up, but I am not sure how to get it there.

Thanks for any suggestions.

I tried to assign an id to the function, and then I put it into a div. The function did not run. I tried using document.write to try and print the image on the page, but again the functoin did not work.

Comment: You may try to include the code for appending into div for us to check if there's any error. Because it should work normally.

Comment: @joshuaOoi OK, I think that it would be something like "document.div.appendChild(newImage)" where I just replace the 'body' element with the 'div' element, for the "child" to 'append' to. But that does not work when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your meaning well. This will be getting ONE random image from the given array and append into a div with id.

You may repeating the "Run code snippet" button to see that it will get the image randomly.

```js
function displayRandomHats()   
{  
   //array of images with image location, height, and width  
  
 var imageArray = [  
   {   
     //address URL of the image  
     src: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/03/13/01/flower-7108886_960_720.jpg",  
     //size for the image to be display on webpage  
     width: "200",  
     height:"200"

       
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/21/02/35/white-faced-heron-7469267_960_720.jpg",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"  
   },   
   {  
     src: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/12/04/15/10/game-7634718_960_720.jpg",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"  
   },  
   {  
     src: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/29/17/40/african-elephants-7624960_960_720.jpg",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"
    },  
   {  
     src: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/15/04/54/automotive-7593064_960_720.jpg",  
     width: "200",  
     height: "200"
    } ];  
      
    //find the length of the array of images  
    var arrayLength = imageArray.length;  
    var newArray = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {  
        newArray[i] = new Image(); 
        newArray[i].src = imageArray[i].src;  
        newArray[i].width = imageArray[i].width;  
        newArray[i].height = imageArray[i].height;  
    }  
     
  // create random image number  
  function getRandomNum(min, max)   
  {  
      // generate and return a random number for the image to be displayed   
      imgNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
      return newArray[imgNo];  
  }    
  
  // 0 is first image and (preBuffer.length - 1) is last image of the array  
  let newImage = getRandomNum(0, newArray.length - 1);  


  document.getElementById("targetDiv").appendChild(newImage);  
}  

displayRandomHats();
```

```html
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```